# Is there any annotation / comments I can put in file for PhpStorm to force file encoding?

Tags: phpstorm

We are using Windows-1252 character-set in one of our files. I have set proper file encoding in Phpstorm > Settings for this particular PHP file. Remaining project is UTF8. This works for me.

The problem comes with other developers in my organization. They have UTF encoding set in their settings and they don't have this file specific custom settings. When they save anything in this file, it converts the special characters.

Is there any doc block OR annotation like

```
// @FILE_ENCODING Windows-1252
```

that I can put in my PHP file so PhpStorm auto detects it?

Comment: Try EditorConfig plugin and `.editorconfig` file in your project -- look at `charset` property: https://github.com/editorconfig/editorconfig/wiki/EditorConfig-Properties#charset Other than that -- I do not know about such annotation (never saw or heard of it in PhpStorm).

Comment: @LazyOne, thanks for suggestions. I was not aware of this. I tried with this suggestion, but it seems like 'windows-1252' charset is not supported by them - https://github.com/editorconfig/editorconfig/issues/209

Comment: Some years ago, when migrating to UTF-8, I'd often add a comment on top of files with a sample of selected characters (`€Áñ`) to help editors' encoding detection. It used to work surprisingly well with the editors I had at the time.